# hv-kvp-daemon fails in Ubuntu 16.04 on Hyper-V

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to automate the deployment of Ubuntu 16.04 VMs on Hyper-V with [packer](https://www.packer.io/) and preseed. In my preseed file I install all required dependencies:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target apt-get install -y --install-recommends linux-virtual-lts-xenial linux-tools-virtual-lts-xenial linux-cloud-tools-virtual-lts-xenial;
```

The installation completes without further problems and after rebooting, the service is running:

```
root@ubunt-xenial:~# systemctl status hv-kvp-daemon.service
 ● hv-kvp-daemon.service - Hyper-V KVP Protocol Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hv-kvp-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-01-15 13:32:34 UTC 12s ago
 Main PID: 567 (hv_kvp_daemon)
 CGroup: /system.slice/hv-kvp-daemon.service
         └─567 /usr/lib/linux-tools/4.4.0-109-generic/hv_kvp_daemon -n

 Jan 15 13:32:34 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: Started Hyper-V KVP Protocol Daemon
 Jan 15 13:32:34 ubuntu-xenial KVP[567]: KVP starting: pid is: 567
 Jan 15 13:32:34 ubuntu-xenial KVP[567]: KVP LIC Version: 3.1
```

But for packer to complete, the hypervisor should be able to see the guest's IP address. But somehow, Hyper-V reports "no contact":

```
D:\packer> Get-VMIntegrationService 'ubuntu-xenial'
[...]
ubuntu-xenial  Key-Value Pair Exchange True   No Contact
```

When I go back in the VM, I see that the service is initially running, but then fails:

```
 root@ubunt-xenial:~# journalctl
 [...]
 Jan 15 13:33:36 ubuntu-xenial kernel: hv_balloon: Received INFO_TYPE_MAX_PAGE_CNT
 Jan 15 13:33:36 ubuntu-xenial kernel: hv_balloon: Data Size is 8
 Jan 15 13:34:26 ubuntu-xenial KVP[567]: read failed; error:9 Bad file descriptor
 Jan 15 13:34:26 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: hv-kvp-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Jan 15 13:34:26 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: hv-kvp-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
 Jan 15 13:34:26 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: hv-kvp-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I restart the service manually with `systemctl restart hv-kvp-daemon.serv ice' it does come up, but fails again after a while. The only option to properly start the daemon is to shutdown the machine and power it on again (reboot does *not* work, I have to start it manually).

For an automated build, I need this service to run, any ideas on fixing this?

tl;dr: hv-kvp-daemon comes up, fails after ~1min and only comes back up after manually restarting it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the machine has been configured with "Data Exchange" enabled?

The option can be found in Hyper-V Manager. Right-click the machine, select "Settings..." -> "Management / Integration Services". Ensure that there is a checkmark next to at least "Data Exchange".

Comment: Yes, Integration Services are enabled. I found a workaround by restarting the hv-kvp-daemon.service every minute and just waiting for it to come up